# How can I transfer colors from first image into second image?

Tags: image-processing, color, image

[image: this is first image]
[image: and this is the second]

How can I transfer colors from first image into second image, where every object from the first image should take the same object's color from first image.
This images are only an example.

this is what i did at fisrt i import my images

```
timage = Import[
   "http://www.theeveryman.com/images/2007/em07p/hstbasils.jpg"]

    rimage1 = 
     Import["http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/\
    2012/3/14/1331719456752/St.-Basils-Cathedral-001.jpg"]
```

and then i find corresponding points between this two images

```
ImageCorrespondingPoints 
images={}

matches = ImageCorrespondingPoints @@ images
MapThread[
 Show[#1, Graphics[{Yellow, 
     MapIndexed[Inset[#2[[1]], #1] & , #2]}]] &, {images, matches}]
```

now i want to transfer colores from my fisrt image into second image?
are there any thing that i should do before this?
 also i used this

```
img=,ref=,
limg = First@ColorSeparate[img, "LAB"];
{lref, aref, bref} = ColorSeparate[ref, "LAB"];
l2 = HistogramTransform[limg, lref];
ImageHistogram /@ {l2, lref}
radius = 2;
{neighimg, neighref} = ColorCombine[{
      MeanFilter[#, radius],
      StandardDeviationFilter[#, radius]}] & /@ {l2, lref};
nfun = Nearest[
   Flatten[ImageData@neighref, 1] -> 
    Transpose[Flatten@ImageData@# & /@ {aref, bref}]];
col = Map[First@nfun[#, 1] &, ImageData@neighimg, {2}];
ColorConvert[
 Image[Join[{ImageData@limg}, Transpose[col, {2, 3, 1}]], 
  Interleaving -> False, ColorSpace -> "LAB"], "RGB"]
```

but i don't know y it gives me wrong result

Comment: This is a difficult task. You first need to match "objects", and those two images are taken from very different POVs. Not trivial at all.

Comment: This two images are only an examples,i did something i find coressponding opjects between my images.

Comment: using ImageCorrespondingPoints

Comment: So post it, and we will see what can be done with the colors!

Comment: i did it ,so can anybody help me?

Comment: you may check HistogramTransform and MatchImageHistograms.